# Visual Basic converting string to currency format

Tags: vb.net, function

I have a function that calculates the totalPrice and returns it in my totalPriceOutputLabel. My problem is, I need the output to be formatted as such "1,222" for example. I know how to convert it as such using

```
ToString("C2")
```

but I am unsure as to how to attach it within my function call. Any ideas?

```
Public Class tileLimitedForm

Private enteredLength, enteredWidth As Double
Private enteredPrice As Decimal

Public Function area(ByRef enteredLength As Double, ByRef enteredWidth As Double)
    area = Val(enteredLength) * Val(enteredWidth)
End Function

Public Function totalPrice(ByRef enteredLength As Double, ByRef enteredWidth As Double)
    totalPrice = Val(area(enteredLength, enteredWidth)) * Val(enteredPrice)
End Function

Private Sub calculateButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles calculateButton.Click

totalPriceOutputLabel.Text = totalPrice(area(enteredLength, enteredWidth),enteredPrice).ToString("C2")

End Sub
```

Comment: Why *calculateButton_Click* and *totalPrice* do the same thing (except the format). It's an error during editing? (*totalPrice* function is currently is calling *totalPrice*)

Comment: I did, that was my mistake. I updated the original posting. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like this:

```
totalPriceOutputLabel.Text = _
    totalPrice(area(enteredLength, enteredWidth), enteredPrice).ToString("C2")
```

It supposes *totalPrice* is a `Double` or other numeric type that supports the `.ToString()` extension with a format parameter.

**EDIT**

After seeing the edited question:

```
 Public Class tileLimitedForm

        Private enteredLength, enteredWidth As Double
        Private enteredPrice As Decimal

        Public Function area(ByVal enteredLength As Double, ByVal enteredWidth As Double) As Double
            area = enteredLength * enteredWidth
        End Function

        Public Function totalPrice(ByVal enteredLength As Double, ByvalenteredWidth As Double) As Double
            totalPrice = area(enteredLength, enteredWidth) * enteredPrice
        End Function

        Private Sub calculateButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles calculateButton.Click
            totalPriceOutputLabel.Text = totalPrice(area(enteredLength, enteredWidth), enteredPrice).ToString("C2")
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Notes:

- You should use `ByVal` instead of `ByRef` in your function in this case
- Your function currently returns an `Object` since you don't set the type that returns the function (you have Option Strict off) => I have added `As Double`.
- No need to use the `Val` since the parameters are already numeric types.

Comment: When implementing what you wrote, I am getting an error regarding an unhandled exception pointing at ("C2"). This error does not really explain how to handle this.

Comment: @user1695704 What type returns the function *totalPrice*? Cab you edit the question with the entire method?